# Twitter Bootstrap: offsetting columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm looking into Bootstrap and am wondering about offsetting columns: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

The documentation says that the columns "should always add up to 12 for each row." Then it gives an example of offsetting columns:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span3 offset2">...</div>
</div>
```

Questions:

1. The columns do not add up to 12. It only totals 7. Or if you count the offset: 9. Was this just a bad example or something?
2. Why would I want to offset anything? Is this just to handle the content of the layout of my site better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clarify what Rob is saying, what you are missing is that all of the grid examples are using 9 columns. The reason is that the sidebar (side navigation) in the docs is itself taking up 3 columns.

The entire width of the bootstrap documentation is 12 columns, minus 3 for the side navigation, which leaves 9 columns for the grid demo. Make sense?

Comment: OK, let's say that the snippet is based on the main content of the Bootstrap documentation. That should be 9, not 4 + 3 = 7. Does the offset count also? 4 + 3 + 2 = 9?

Comment: That's correct, the offset counts as well. Think of an offset as an empty column. Each offset increment equals one .span1. So .offset2 = .span2

Answer (score 2):

The sidebar is a span3. So the entire page width adds up to 12. The content section it's displayed in is only a span9.

Comment: Sorry. How does the sidebar being span3 make the width add to 12?

Comment: Because the entire page width is 12 columns. The sidebar is 3 columns and the main content section is 9 columns. Therefore, anything in the main content section can only add up to 9. Same if you were to put more columns in a span 3. That would only fit 3 columns, not 12.

Comment: How did you figure out the main content section is 9? All I see from the snippet I put are span4, span3 and offset2. My confusion is that the numbers do not add up to 12.